# Is there console.log equivalent in Laravel?

Tags: php, debugging, laravel

Sometimes I would like to print something out to the console for quick debugging when I am working with Node.js.

I have tried `print` and `echo` but nothing seems to work. Oh and I am runnign `php artisan serve` command if it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork), which is a `Chrome` extension for `PHP` development, extending Developer Tools with a new panel providing all kinds of information useful for debugging and profiling your `PHP` applications, including information about request, headers, get and post data, cookies, session data, database queries, routes, visualisation of application runtime and more. To install latest version simply add it to your `composer.json`:

```
"itsgoingd/clockwork": "1.*"
```

Then, you need to register `Larave`l service provider:

```
'providers' => array(
    ...
    'Clockwork\Support\Laravel\ClockworkServiceProvider'
)
```

You can register the facade in your `app/config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Clockwork' => 'Clockwork\Support\Laravel\Facade',
)
```

To add your controller's `runtime` to timeline, you may add following to your base controller's constructor:

```
$this->beforeFilter(function()
{
    Event::fire('clockwork.controller.start');
});

$this->afterFilter(function()
{
    Event::fire('clockwork.controller.end');
});
```

Now, if you use these:

```
// Event called 'Event description.' appears in Clockwork timeline tab
Clockwork::startEvent('event_name', 'Event description.');

// 'Message text.' appears in Clockwork log tab
Clockwork::info('Message text.');
```

Read the manual on [Github](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) for nore information. You may use this for query logging and it'll provide full log including query time etc and many more. Install it from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clockwork/dmggabnehkmmfmdffgajcflpdjlnoemp?hl=en).

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlQqV.png) of `Chrome's Inspection Tool` with `ClockWork` instealled:
[image]